# How to fetch data from database before rendering in a function componment in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Below is my code:

```
function Profile() {
    const {userInfo} = useSelector(state => state.user);
    let user = {};

    useEffect(() => {
        const populateUserInfo = async () => {
            const {data} = await axios.get("api/users/" + userInfo._id);
            user = data

            // this line works if I comment out {user.shipping.address} in the "return" section.
            console.log(user.shipping.address) 
        }
        populateUserInfo();
    }, [])

    return <div>{user.shipping.address}</div>
}
```

I want to fetch data from DB and store it into `user` variable before rendering, but when the page renders, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined` occurred.

I guess the `user` variable is still empty when the page renders?
Could anyone teach me how to do it?

Comment: @JosephD. Like I said in the comment, `console.log(user.shipping.address) ` works. So I think `data` contains the correct data.

Comment: make `user` a state.

Comment: @JosephD. I tried but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `user` a state and do conditional render.

Initially, `user` is not set.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(); // null

useEffect(
  () => {
    const populateUserInfo = async () => {
      const {data} = await axios.get("api/users/" + userInfo._id);
      setUser(data);
    }

    populateUserInfo();
  }
  , []
)

return (
  user ? (
    <div>{user.shipping.address}</div>
    : null
  );
);
```

Comment: It works, thank you. I think it is the conditional render that does the trick.

Comment: @powerseed, well I do advise making a `user` a state in case you plan to do mutation with the `user` object in your component. if `user` is not a state and you do a mutation, your component won't re-render.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, you are updating your user variable only inside the useEffect function which is local. You need it to get updated outside that function as well.

To do this, I would suggest to use useState instead. 
Declare the user state outside the function as so:

`const [user, setUser] = useState({});`

Inside the profile function, replace:

`let user = {};`

With:

`setUser({});`

Then inside the useEffect function, replace:

`user = data;`

With:

`setUser({data});`

Answer (score 0):

You can also fetch it with a [react standard async method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) with an example on this page [componentDidMount](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react/).

The class method [componentDidMount](https://rapidapi.com/blog/react-hooks-fetch-data-api/#useeffect-vs-componentdidmount) is only supposed to run at the beginning of the lifecycle.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
   userData: null
        };
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/42`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ userData: json }));
    }
    
 render() {
  return (
            <div>
               {this.state.userData ? "user title: " + this.state.userData.title : "Waiting for user ..."} 
            </div>
  );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'></div>
```

Comment: But I cannot use it in a function component, can I?

Comment: @powerseed yes, you cannot use it in a function component. I added a link for this question. Nevertheless, you asked for (maybe one time) rendering at the beginning and I did'nt read the "component function" in the heading. I thought, it could be also a solution in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `async-await` inside `useEffect()`

instead, you can use this.

and I edited some parts of your code.

```
function Profile() {
    const {userInfo} = useSelector(state => state.user);
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState({});
    async function populateUserInfo(){
       let user = {};
       const {data} = await axios.get("api/users/" + userInfo._id);
       setUser(data);
       console.log(data.shipping.address) 
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        populateUserInfo();
    }, [])

    return <div>{user.shipping.address}</div>
}
```

Comment: I tried you code but it doesn't work. Thank you all the same